# Send Data from sqlite to server request is not sending in android?

Tags: android, sqlite

Data is not sending to server.Here am fetching data from sqlite, store into variable and send to server using url.I think so inside try connections are fine but dataoutputstreem, writebyte and buffereader only giving some problem.

```
public class Main extends Activity {    
    String names,numbers,areas,citys;
    ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_data = new ArrayList<GSdemovote>();
    DatabaseHandler db;
    GSdemovote contact;
    String n,nn,a,c;    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        contact_data.clear();
        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_array_from_db = db.getAllGSdemovotes();    
        for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

            //int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
            names = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
            numbers = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
            areas = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getArea();
            citys = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCity();
            execute( names,numbers,areas,citys);                            
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), names+numbers+areas+citys, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void execute(String names,String numbers,String areas,String citys){

        try {
            n = URLEncoder.encode(names, "utf-8");
            nn = URLEncoder.encode(numbers, "utf-8");
            a = URLEncoder.encode(areas, "utf-8");
            c = URLEncoder.encode(citys, "utf-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String str = "";
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream inStream = null;

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        String urlString  = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/tsubba/demovotes.php?&name="+n +"&number="+nn+"&area="+a+"&city="+c;

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), n+nn+a+c, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setDoInput(true);

            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);

            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

            String inputLine;

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(inputLine);
            }
            fileInputStream.close();

            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
        }

        catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        }

        catch (IOException ioe) {
        }       

    }   

}
```

help me , thanks advance.

Comment: Not sure if it's your problem, but `demovotes.php?&name` should be `demovotes.php?name=`, the `&` separator should be only between parameters, not before the first.

Comment: Thanks for information.I changes `demovotes.php?&name` to `demovotes.php?name=` still not running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some try I got this solution, its working well..

```
    public class Main extends Activity {

    String names,numbers,areas,citys;
    ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_data = new ArrayList<GSdemovote>();
    DatabaseHandler db;
    GSdemovote contact;
    String n,nn,a,c;        
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        contact_data.clear();
            db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            ArrayList<GSdemovote> contact_array_from_db = db.getAllGSdemovotes();       
            for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                //int tidno = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getID();
                names = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getName();
                numbers = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getPhoneNumber();
                areas = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getArea();
                citys = contact_array_from_db.get(i).getCity();

                execute(names,numbers,areas,citys);
                long rows = i+1;
                if(rows == contact_array_from_db.size()){
                    db.deleteGSdemovote(contact);
                }                       
            }
        }
        public void execute(String names,String numbers,String areas,String citys){

        try {
            n = URLEncoder.encode(names, "utf-8");
            nn = URLEncoder.encode(numbers, "utf-8");
            a = URLEncoder.encode(areas, "utf-8");
            c = URLEncoder.encode(citys, "utf-8");

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader=null;

        String urlParameters =  "name="+n+"&number="+nn+"&area="+a+"&city="+c;

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/android/registration.php?");            

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD){
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }

            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.flush();

            // Get the response 


         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         String line = null;


            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Application", "exception", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                reader.close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex) {}
        }
    }   
}
```